# Unable to configure system email address in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Tried everything, still unable to set system email address in Jenkins.

1. Tried setting system email under Manage Jenkins>Configure settings
2. Tried updating JenkinsLocationConfiguration xml file

Still issue persist, any help will be appreciated

Comment: 1)launch Jenkins.
2)access Manage Jenkins link from the main page.
3)go to the end of the page and fill Email notification details.
4)Click on Test notification to verify it is sending an email.
5)Please see the email sent from Jenkins.

Comment: I am receiving email notification with sender's email as "Address not configured yet" . I updated system email's address as "Jenkins <donotreply@jenkins.com>" but it doesn't work.

Comment: you need to configure SMTP server details in extended email notification. please refer below page as reference.https://medium.com/@pradeep.sg406/how-to-configure-email-notification-in-jenkins-227b58d3c017#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Jenkins%20home,'Use%20SMTP%20Authentication'%20option.

Comment: Hi, I tried, I am able to receive email but still sender's email is coming with "Address not configured yet"

Comment: This works fine with Email notificaiton plugin, the issue is only with Editable email notification plugin.

Comment: Finally it worked by updating Email Ext plugin to 2.79, mailer to 1.32 and token macro to 2.12. It seems the old plugins are outdated.